# How to recover NTFS partitions after Installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery, ntfs

Usually I install Ubuntu Alongside windows , this time I decide to make Ubuntu the main system so I choose erase disk blah blah option which has a description say "It will delete my documents , photos , videos and the windows system" in installation screen , After Ubuntu successfully installed

## I found my NTFS partitions [C:,D:,E:,F:] Deleted

I know this question is duplicated , but I really don't know how to recover it

Also `TestDisk` is not available choice ; Because I'm not going to buy a new hardDisk to recover files on it

---

Please I beg you guys, about 200GB of my work and 80GB of programs deleted

Comment: @user68186 no I think it will delete the windows documents,photo folders not my data partitions , also I will buy a hard disk but while searching i found that the new hard disk size must be over than the old one so I will need a 512GB hard disk which worth  in my currency about 1k EGP , it's huge number !!

Comment: Why would you choose the erase disk option when you were aware that it would erase everything???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to tell you that,there is no anyway out of this with out using a recovery tool,[Test disk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk) for example,and the more bad news is,,if you keep using that fresh installed ubuntu,you will keep on overwriting everything in a previous partition and odds are later on it will be to late to recovery any thing with the recovery tool!

Simple answers is,no!there is no any other way than using the recovery tools to rescue your lost data.

Comment: If I buy a new hard disk  and use `testdisk` what's the successful percent of recovery ?

Comment: it depends on how much the previous data was overwritten

Comment: if not tempered,then 80% of data will be recovered

Comment: Thank you for giving me you time :) , I think i will do a fresh start from 0 !